# Uncertainty and sensitivity analysis on modelling problems

Tags: references, modeling, uncertainty, sensitivity-analysis

I am starting to write the literature review for a project and my supervisor wants me to do an Uncertainty analysis and sensitivity analysis for a Modelica model he has. I am new to both concepts, do you have any suggestions for literature to:

1. Understand the difference between them?
2. How they are calc.
3. How the results are presented after those analyses.

Comment: There are a number of questions on this site tagged [tag:sensitivity-analysis]. Perhaps you could review them again and then clarify what you do not understand? A the moment the answer might fill a text-book.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am aware that the answer is quite long, i was looking for advice on good papers or articles to begin with, do you have any ? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Since you refer to an engineering model, I will give a common example in engineering/science. A model is used to interpret data that you have collected to estimate a parameter, $\theta$. Suppose the model has an internal parameter, $\eta$, the value of which is uncertain. If you adjust the assumed value for $\eta$, the estimated parameter $\hat\theta$ changes. You can characterize the sensitivity of the estimator to $\eta$, in a variety of ways, for example $s=\Delta E[\hat\Theta]/\Delta\eta$. You could also characterize the uncertainty in $\theta$ that arises from the uncertainty in $\eta$, for example by $\delta_\theta = s\, \delta_\eta$.